# How I can prove that $e^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}$ is class $C^{\infty}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, induction

I want to prove that the function $f(x,y)$ is class $\space C^{\infty}$, I was thinking about proving it for $\space e^{-\frac{1}{x+y}} \space$ and then make the composition of $\space f(h(x,y)) \space$ with $\space h(x,y)=(x^2,y^2)$, because composition of class $\space C^{\infty} \space$  is class $\space C^{\infty} \space$.

$f(x,y)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             e^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}} &   if  & (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
             \\ 0 &  if & (x,y)=(0,0) \\
             \end{array}
   \right.$

It's easy to prove that $f(x,y)$ is continious at $(0,0)$ but How I can prove it for all $\space f^{k}(x,y)$?, thank you!

Comment: let $r(x,y)$  be any rational function. Then the limit of $f  r$  at the origin is zero. Furthermore, every partial derivative of $f$  is of the form $f  r$ for some such $r$

Comment: @WillJagy, it's similar to the proof for $e^{x}$?, using simetry for the partials, right?

Comment: similar to the proof for $e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}} $

Comment: @WillJagy, thank you!

Comment: @WillJagy, another question, How I can prove that $f^{k}(0,0)=0$ for all k?

Comment: Note that $e^{-\frac1{x+y}}$ is not defined along $y=x$, so this is not a good approach.